# Actions of Controllers not working in SIlverstripe

Tags: php, content-management-system, silverstripe

I followed exactly what the documentation said: Controllers are automatically rendered with a template that makes their name. Our TeamsController would be rendered with a TeamsController.ss template. Individual actions are rendered in TeamsController_{actionname}.ss. templates/TeamsController.ss works but the ones for actions does not, for example one allowed action is someaction so I created a templates/TeamsController_someaction but is not outputting at all all I get is a blank. Obly works if i use renderWith. Can somebody explain please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just do a return $this..not sure which ones are returned but for sure your template is.